# How do you add the Allegro library to CodeBlocks?

Tags: libraries, code-blocks

I’m trying to add the Allegro library to the CodeBlocks IDE.  Until recently I had been using windows, which meant going to programs -> CodeBlock and then adding the libraries folders into the appropriate CodeBlocks folders, then going into CodeBlocks and taking care of the linkers.

Since linix doesn’t use this method I’m not really sure what where I put the folders, or what I’m supposed to do to be able to use Allegro or other libraries in CodeBlocks on ubuntu.